# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'i' is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift

I wrote my code, but errors happened.

What's wrong in my code?

```
class UserCollectionViewModel {

    var userDataArray:[[String]] = []

    func getUserDevData(userId: String) -> Array<[String]> {
        for i in userDataArray{
            i.append([]) // Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'i' is a 'let' constant
            i[0].append("Alpha") // Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'i' is a 'let' constant
        }
        return userDataArray
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve by appending?

Comment: Even if you fix the errors, the logic makes no sense. Since `userDataArray` starts out empty, the loop won't do anything.

Comment: @MridulGupta thx for comment. just want to fix this error.

Comment: @rmaddy thx for comment. I only wish I could fix it to the correct syntax.

Comment: Until you gives a better idea of what you are trying to do with this code, providing a proper solution is difficult.

Comment: Your code makes no sense, as you've been told. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Scott, we get that you want to fix the error, but no one can tell what the error-free case should look like. For instance, one way to get rid of the errors would be to delete the `getUserDevData` function, but clearly that wouldn't help you very much. While you may know what you want to say in code, to a reader, right now, this is not obvious at all because there are more errors than just the two that the compiler is showing you. This is why you're being asked to take a step back and explain what your goal (beyond fixing the immediate error) is.

Comment: Thank you All :) Really helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift arrays are value types, not reference types. It means that in this code:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var copy = array
copy.append(5)
```

`copy` now has 5 elements, but `array` still just has its initial set of 4 elements.

The same is true from `for` loops:

```
let arrayOfArrays = [[1], [2], [3]]
for array in arrayOfArrays {
    // array is a *copy* of one of the sub-arrays of `arrayOfArrays`.
}
```

You can iterate over the array's indices instead:

```
func getUserDevData(userId: String) -> [[String]] {
    for i in userDataArray.indices {
        userDataArray[i].append([])
        userDataArray[i][0].append("Alpha")
    }
    return userDataArray
}
```

I'm not really sure that this is what you want either, though, because your code (as it stands) doesn't type-check. `i.append([])` is an impossible operation because `i` is a `[String]`: you can only `append` `String` values to it, not empty arrays, and `i.append(contentsOf: [])` makes no sense because it does nothing.

So I hope that this example gets you unblocked, but there's clearly a behavior problem here too. Fixing compiler errors isn't helpful if your program still isn't working.

Comment: why do you want to use map function to create another array and use extra space and then return. I have edited my answer please have a look

Answer (score 0):

please look at this.

```
class UserCollectionViewModel {

var userDataArray:[[String]] = []

var strinArray =  [String]()
func getUserDevData(userId: String) -> Array<[String]> {
    for index in 0..<userDataArray.count {
        userDataArray[index].append(contentsOf: [])
        userDataArray[index][0].append("alpha")
    }
    return userDataArray
}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That almost certainly isn't what OP wants: `i` is a copy of the array in `userDataArray`, appending to it won't have any visible effect.

Comment: While this fixes the error, the code doesn't do anything because the array is empty.

Comment: @maddy: I've already asked him what is he trying to achieve, other than fixing compilation issues this code does nothing.